# How to access a variable in whole SQL server database project?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I use Visual studio and I created SQL server database project. Is there any option to create variable in pre-deployment script
e.g. `:setvar TableName dbo.Person` and have access to it in whole project (when I want to create stored procedure)?